# Piezo Buzzer Driver Circuit

Tags: transistors, driver, piezo-buzzer

I haven’t used a buzzer before so I have tried to find out as much I could and finally, I am here to clear my few doubts:

**Few details about my application**:

Buzzer: AST1240MLTRQ (i was not allowed to post more than two links, but it can be found easily)

Peak-Peak Signal, Single Tone, 4kHz, Piezo, voltage range: 1 ~ 25V, 75dB @ 3V, 10cm, 5mA current-supply.

Power supply from cr2032 (~ 3V). My MCU’s one pin can handle only 5mA current. MCU can handle 15mA in total.

**Questions**

So, after keeping in mind everything above I have following doubts/ questions:

1. Recommended circuit (just below question 3) is given in this datasheet at page 8 (http://www.mallory-sonalert.com/Documents/TechAppGuides/PAG-Transducers-External%20Drive-Piezo.pdf or see the image directly )

Since, I have MCU to generate PWM, I do not need oscillator circuit. If I am using transistor with gain 50 and collector current is 5mA according to datasheet then base current should be = (MCU pin voltage – 700mV)/ base resistor. If I use 50% of duty cycle (3/2=1.5V average volttage on MCU pin) then

->base current = (1.5V- 700mV)/base resistor,

->(Collector current/ gain) = (0.8v)/ Base resistor,

=>Base resistor= 8K ohm.
Is that right way to calculate the base resistor?

2. Now, in this recommended circuit (just below question 3), inductor value is given as a sample value. The question is that, **why do we need this inductor**, although it is said in the datasheet just below the circuit on page 8 (or see the image directly) that, inductor is optional, what does that line mean (that’s kind of ambiguous (for e.g., is it saying that inductor is optional or is it saying that value of the inductor is optional))?
3. **If that inductor is to be used** then how do I calculate the value of this inductor for my application?

[image]

4. Or may i use a collector resistor of 1k in parallel to the buzzer and not use the inductor at all?
5. I could have posted question with more clarity but wasn't allowed as i don't have community reputation. Apologies for the mistakes, i am still learning to walk in hardware design.

Comment: If I were to recommend a course of action it would be to use a piezo buzzer with a built in driver.

Comment: In addition to @Scott's recommendation, the CR2032 is rated for continuous 200uA. Something like that. It can do 5mA... but that's more for short periods of operation and the voltage significantly drops, as well; perhaps by 400mV. Are you planning the entire circuit driven off the CR2032?

Comment: How many buzzers do you plan to incorporate? Just one? And yes, you can just drive that buzzer from the micro if you plan to generate the 4kHz at the pin itself. But you will need a few cheap parts between the micro and the buzzer, I think.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I can't afford to have buzzer having dimensions bigger than current buzzer i am using. I am afraid that built in driver will turn out to be bigger.

Comment: @jonk i am planning to run entire circuit on CR2032. I could switch to this buzzer AST1109MLTRQ (Peak-Peak Signal Buzzer Single Tone 4.1kHz Piezo 1 ~ 20V 73dB @ 5V, 10cm, 1 mA current Max.). I am planning to use only one buzzer. If you have some buzzer in mind within same limitations as my requirement then please let me know. Inductor is what bothering me in the recommended circuit. My guess is that it dumps charge on the capacitive buzzer while BJT is off to increase voltage so that it can play louder but not sure.

Comment: http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/audio-products/alarms-buzzers-and-sirens/720967?k=&pkeyword=&pv1398=6&FV=fff4000b%2Cfff80047&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25  -- they go as small as 9mmx5mm

Comment: @ScottSeidman Yes, i considered them but then height shouldn't go more than 3.5 mm in my case, or 4 mm if i stretch the limitations.

Comment: The inductor has a higher resistance to AC and since the transistor is CE, the gain is increased (but the underlying DC is unaffected).  So, you were on the right track with your earlier comment;-)  Check this out: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amp_2.html

Comment: @Fauzi: You have an answer about the inductor, now. The CR2032 shouldn't be loaded more than about 1-2mA, total, if continuous. Their mAh rating is at 200uA, though. So lower is better and you should measure the delivered voltage at the draw you do use and be sure that it is okay. (If you design to expect 2.8V, I'm sure you will be fine.) Of course, you can do what you want to the cell. But if you need a lot more current and can accept a different shape/volume, you should be looking at a different battery cell.

Comment: @jonk  most of the problem has been solved. Regarding the value of inductor, i will try hit and trial method to get loud audio out of buzzer. I will keep in mind your advice.

Comment: @Buck8pe: Thanks for the link, now things make sense to me :)

Comment: You should be able to post links now. | Using two pins to drive a buzzer push pull doubles the voltage and increases available power by a factor of 4, subject to pin current capabilities.